# Header links also appearing in the footer

Tags: theme-development, menus

In my menu area of the word press admin I have access to place links in both the h "main menu" and the "footer links"

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'main_nav' => 'The Main Nav',
    'footer_links' => 'The Footer Links'
));
```

In the Header:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'The Main Nav'));
```

In the Footer:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'The Footer Links'));
```

In the header Nav, I have a link to the default sample page, in the footer I have a link to google. I save the menus and look at the front end, I get the sample page link in both the header and the footer.

for further proof that I have two menus:

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to get a specific menu is the `'theme_location'` parameter:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'main_nav'));
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer_links'));
```

Comment: Thought so, I read something on that, i though menu would do the same